# How to extract URL of created html form using google app script

Tags: google-apps-script, url, google-sheets

I'm using google app script to build something like a form that helps me with automation.

here's the code for building my form

```
<div class="w3-container w3-section">
    <div class="form-container">
      <div class="spacing">
        <input class="input-like" placeholder="Enter video link" id="vid" type="text"/>
      </div>

  <div class="spacing">
    <select class="input-like" id="vcategory">
      <option value='' disabled selected hidden>Select video category</option>
      <option value='Film & Animation'>Film & Animation</option>
      <option value='Autos & Vehicles'>Autos & Vehicles</option>
      <option value='Pets & Animals'>Pets & Animals</option>
      <option value='Sports'>Sports</option>
      <option value='Travel & Events'>Travel & Events</option>
      <option value='Gaming'>Gaming</option>
      <option value='People & Blogs'>People & Blogs</option>
      <option value='Comedy'>Comedy</option>
      <option value='Entertainment'>Entertainment</option>
      <option value='News & Politics'>News & Politics</option>
      <option value='How to & Style'>How to & Style</option>
      <option value='Education'>Education</option>
      <option value='Science & Technology'>Science & Technology</option>
      <option value='Nonprofits & Activism'>Nonprofits & Activism</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="button-wrapper">
  <button class="w3-blue" onclick="addRow()">Add</button>
</div>

<div class="button-wrapper">
  <div class="alert alert-success" id="ok" style="display:none">
    <h3>Thanks</h3>
    <p>This is a new one</p>
  </div>

  <div class="alert alert-danger" id="warn" style="display:none">
    <h3>Duplicate!</h3>
    <p>The video ID or Name is already on the list</p>
  </div>

  <div class="alert alert-warning" id="missing" style="display:none">
    <h3>Input missing!</h3>
    <p>Viedo link or Category is missing</p>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

At this point everything works fine and I can see my Form when I deploy.

I get the forms values through a function that send these values to doGet() function and I add them to the spreadsheet cells.

What I want to do, is when I do run this script .. it sends me to a new tab containing the created form, as this form is not created as a submenu in the spreadsheet, it's completely in another page/tab .. I want to get this page/tab url as I need to access it's parameters in the future.

I tried to use [google.script.url](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/url) as in the documentation but it sent me empty object,

I tried to use window.location.href, it sent me a weird URL that I couldn't recognize and it's not the one for the created tab.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: There is no form node

Comment: Depending upon what you are trying to accomplish, a dialog might suffice with a google.script.run and the use of form tag you can send it as an object as long as you have no restricted values

Comment: @Cooper is there's a way that I add some kind of parameter with my hand and retrieve it.
I know it's seems like I want to do something stupid, but this is required kinda :D  

What I mean, If the url is www.something.com , I want add to it manually to be www.something.com/x=10, and then return this complete url using scruptApp.getService ?

Comment: If you read the link it says "Returns the URL of the web app, if it has been deployed; otherwise returns null." so no you can't hardwire ScriptApp.getService().getUrl but that doesn't necessarly mean you can put in a URL.  Again I don't know what you are trying to do.  PLease provide addition explanation and then another alternative may come to light.

Comment: If you wish to add query parameters to a url you must terminate the url with ? and add parameter separated with & and possibly url encode them

Comment: What I want to do specifically is sending this created form, to several pple to fill it with data, and I extract these data and put them on a spreadsheet, which happens successfully but I was trying to differentiate between forms, as I can send several ones differently in parameters.

Comment: Something like, www.something.com?type=comedy .. I'll send this form to several pple to fill it, and I want in the spreadsheet to extract comedy,

the next one i'll remove comedy put it as politics so it will reflect in the spreadsheet too as politics now, but all this with the same form that's why I was saying I'm adding params manually.

Comment: Since you are using a webapp the query parameters are available in the event object of the doGet(e).

Comment: @Cooper, Thanks a lot, I appreciate your help

Comment: Note your html does not contain a form tag so you cannot post the form data as an object unless you assemble all of the indivdual elements yourself in javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ScriptApp.getService().getUrl()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/service)

Comment: Thanks, this actually made me get the url